# NodeError: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object when using nightmare

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm currently having a nightmare...

I have been running this code:

```
nightmare
    .goto('https://www.google.com')
    .end(() => 'some value')
    //prints "some value"
    .then(console.log)
```

On 2 projects, on with an electron window running in the background and one without.

The one without the electron window works completely fine, but when I open the electron window on the other project I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) NodeError: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object

I have searched for a very long time and can't seem to find anything about it.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm running the this from a class function, example:

```
Class test{
    async test(){
        nightmare
    .goto('https://www.google.com')
    .end(() => 'some value')
    //prints "some value"
    .then(console.log)
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
nightmare
.goto('https://www.google.com')
.end(() => 'some value')
//prints "some value"
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

?